# Phonegap 3.2.0 File Plugin Warnings in DirectoryManager class

Tags: android, file, plugins, cordova, warnings

I'm developing a Phonegap 3.2 app for Android (4.3).

I'm using the File plugin.

Everything is working fine BUT I get 2 warning in the File plugin, in DirectoryManager.java:

```
long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
```

both of those functions are 'deprecated'.

I can add 'SuppressWarnings', but It's probably not a good solution.

Yes, I've removed and installed this plugin again, nothing changed.

What can be done to prevent those warnings ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the "freeSpaceCalculation" function, is that a good solution ?

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private static long freeSpaceCalculation(String path) {
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path);
    long blockSize;
    long availableBlocks;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
        blockSize = stat.getBlockSizeLong();
        availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocksLong();
    }else{
        blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
        availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
    }

    return availableBlocks * blockSize / 1024;
}
```